# Why to use "redundant" keyword "struct" for types in Go?

Tags: go, struct, syntax

I am a big fan of Golang, and very pleased to how the syntax of Go is designed. As a part of syntax philosophy, we have a rule as following: omit the things (keywords, characters etc.) if they are not needed actually.

For that reason instead of writing redundant colons:

```
for ; sum < 1000; {
    sum += sum
}
```

You allowed to simply put:

```
for sum < 1000 {
    sum += sum
}
```

*notice how we omitted redundant semicolons*

And there are lots of other cases where syntax is gratefully simplified.

But what about `struct` when we define type?

```
type Person struct {
    name string
}
```

Why do we need to put `struct` keyword here?
Keywords are to determine intention, to clarify the exact choice of available options so a compiler knows how to do his job properly.

Will it be unclear and ambiguous if we simply put:

```
type Person {
    name string
}
```

??

> I believe there is a meaning for `struct` in the examples above
>   because compiler fails when type defined without `struct` keyword.

Please, explain me (and provide links) **what else** we can use instead of `struct` when we define some type.

Please, list available options from which we want to clarify to a compiler that things in curly brackets after type name are exactly parts of a **struct** and not something else (**what else**?).

Thanks.

Comment: Grammar rules are grammar rules. While it *could* implicitly assume `struct` if not provided, such is not allowed by the Go language/grammar. Thus it's not allowed. (The Go grammar has been specifically designed to *avoid* much grammar complexity..)

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? It's a good question.

Comment: @ThunderCat You expect beginners to read the language spec? Give me a break

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not redundant. You can make types from existing types:

```
type MyType int
type MyType string
```

Or interfaces:

```
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}
```

This is covered [in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) and [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations).

Comment: *Part* of the question the OP is asking why `type T {..}` can't be implicitly treated as `type T struct {..}` (and that part is OT).

Comment: OP explicitly asks: "Please, explain me (and provide links) what else we can use instead of struct when we define some type."

Comment: The part where it was edited into your comment after the fact. I answered what seemed to be the root of the question.

Comment: I see, thanks for providing options. But also, yes, my intention was to understand why we can't just use `type T {..}` with `struct` in mind as a default behavior.

Comment: That is a question for the Go maintainers, not for StackOverflow. If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say they didn't chose `struct` as a default because it would be an arbitrary choice - there's no reason it makes a better default than anything else, so there is no default.

Answer (score 2):

[Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) (may) not only appear in [type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations), but in countless other places, for example in [function declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations).

Structs may be "used" anonymously, without creating a named type for them. For example, the following declaration is  valid:

```
func GetPoint() struct{ x, y int } {
    return struct{ x, y int }{1, 2}
}
```

Without having to use the `struct` keyword, **a parsing ambiguity would arise in multiple uses**. Let's say we want to create a function which returns an empty struct:

```
func GetEmpty() struct{} {
    return struct{}{}
}
```

How would this look like without the `struct` keyword?

```
func GetEmpty2() {} {
    return {}{}
}
```

Now if you're the compiler, what would *you* make out of this? Is this a function with the same signature as `GetEmpty()`? Or is this a function without a return value and an empty body (`func GetEmpty2() {}`) followed by a [block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) which contains a `return` statement? The return statement would be another ambiguity, as it may return nothing which is followed by 2 empty blocks, or it may return an empty struct value which is followed by an empty block...

Now to avoid parsing ambiguity, we have to use the `struct` keyword when specifying struct types *elsewhere* (outside of type declarations), then why make it optional or disallow it in type declarations?
I think a **consistent syntax** is more important than grabbing all chances to reduce the language (syntax) to the minimum possible. That hurts readability big time. The `for` loop example you mentioned is not really a simplification, but rather the usage of different forms of the `for` loop.

Comment: Totally agree, that's why my question scoped only to `type`. I understand the value of `struct` for other places, but `type Person {name string}` looks straightforward and recognized for instance in TypeScript.

Comment: If you have to use the `struct` keyword "outside" of type declarations to specify the type (anonymous type), why would you want to change the type's "appearance" in type declaration? Isn't it more straightforward to use the same in all places?

Comment: I think a consistent syntax is more important than grabbing all chances to reduce the language (syntax) to the minimum possible. That hurts readability big time. The `for` loop example you mentioned is not really a simplification, but rather the usage of different forms of the `for` loop.

Comment: I am pursuing simplicity. If we roughly call `struct` an unnamed temporary type, then `type Person struct {name string}` _looks like_ we create named type `Person` that infers from unnamed type `anonymous struct`. You see? We engaged two types instead of just one named type.

Comment: @OleksiiShnyra I don't see, because this initial hypothesis in your comment _"if we roughly call `struct` an unnamed temporary type"_ is not true. `struct` itself is just a keyword, `struct{}` is the anonymous empty struct type.

Comment: I think this question appeared because I am using TypeScript. Thus, one more keyword (`struct` after `type`) seems strange (redundant) to me yet.
The consistent syntax is more important - good point btw.